# group by a random not null entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `usercolor` like this:

```
 id  | idUser  | color
-----------------------
 1   |  1      | red
 2   |  1      | blue 
 3   |  2      | green 
 4   |  2      | blue
 5   |  3      | null
 6   |  3      | blue
 7   |  4      | null
```

I would like to have for each `idUser` one random fitting color which is not null whenever possible. Like this:

```
idUser | color
---------------
1      | blue
2      | green
3      | blue
4      | null
```

I thought I could achieve it by

```
SELECT idUser, color FROM usercolor GROUP BY idUser
```

However, with this SQL it might happen that `idUser` 3 is mapped to null although there exists the color blue for that `idUser`. How could I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one random color per user, then a correlated subquery comes to mind:

```
select idUser,
       (select uc.color
        from usercolor uc
        where uc.idUser = u.idUser and uc.color is not null
        order by rand()
        limit 1
       ) as color
from (select distinct idUser from usercolor) u  -- you can use `users` here instead
```

Comment: I mean one color that belongs to the user, but since one user might have multiple colors, it might be picked randomly. If I understand correctly, then you map each user with a random color that appears in the database, right?

Comment: @Adam . . . You are right.  It needed a correlation clause.